# Round a SQL value output?

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

script:

```
SELECT DEPTNO, COUNT(EMPNO), SUM(SAL), AVG(SAL)
  FROM EMP
 GROUP BY DEPTNO
 ORDER BY AVG(SAL) DESC;
```

return:

```
  DEPTNO    COUNT(EMPNO) SUM(SAL)   AVG(SAL)
 ---------  ------------ --------  -----------
    10            3       8750     2916.66667
    20            5      10875           2175
    30            6       9400     1566.66667
    40            1       1500           1500
```

---

> I would like to round the decimals on the two values with decimals in the AVG(SAL)column. Thoughts/advice?

Comment: Well, the function that *counts* is called `COUNT`, the function that *sums* is called `SUM`, … how may the function that *rounds* may be called? :-)

Answer (score 3):

use `round()`

```
SELECT DEPTNO, COUNT(EMPNO),round( SUM(SAL),2),round( AVG(SAL),2)
FROM EMP GROUP BY DEPTNO ORDER BY AVG(SAL) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    SELECT DEPTNO, 
      COUNT(EMPNO), 
      SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2),SAL)),  
      AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2),SAL)) 
   FROM EMP GROUP BY DEPTNO 
   ORDER BY 
       AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2),SAL)) DESC;
```

Comment: The question is tagged for Oracle, so this syntax isn't valid. (I would also think you'd round after the aggregation, not before?)